# Scaling Problems with Text and Paths. JellyBean Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, canvas, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I got an Update with JellyBean on my Samsung Galaxy Tab ( GT-N8010 ).

When scaling a text with canvas the text is unsharp and ugly. Before JellyBean Update the text was smooth and precise.

The same app (apk) in the AVD emulator ( Android 4.1 ) and on Samsung Galaxy II looks also fine.

following picture, which was uplaoded in good quality ( original size ) shows the ugly text. This behavior is on Samsung Galaxy Tab (GT-N8010,Android 4.1.2 ), Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.2.1), Acer Iconia A-500 (4.0.3), HTC Tell (4.0.3)
[image]

Should be like the following picture and worked before JellyBean on my Galaxy Tab and works still on my Samsung Galaxy II (GT-I9100, Android 4.0.4) and in the Emulator:
[image]

Any hints ?

My simple Code : ( The is complete and can be copied for testing )

```
package com.example.textactivities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class TestJellyBeanScaling extends Activity {

    Drawtest drawtest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawtest = new Drawtest(this);
        setContentView(drawtest);

    }
    private class Drawtest extends View  {

        public Drawtest(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            canvas.scale(10,10);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(20);
            canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess i have to rewrite my hole code with path.transform(scale,scale) & .settextsize(scale*TEXTSIZE) ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:
With my new JellyBean Update Hardware acceleration was defaulted to on and Hardwareacceleration seams to be buggy. I had to explicity false the "Hardware acceleration" in the AndroidManifest.xml :

```
    <application
   android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

`paint.setAntiAlias(true);`

set anti alias for the paint, that will be more smooth.

Comment: AntiAlias did not solve the problem. I know this method, but even if i wouldn't set antialias to true it should not look that ugly as shown in the picture. Even with antialiasing it looks bad since JellyBean. Any other help ?